# How to calculate the curvature of a curve whose equation is not given.

Tags: geometry

[image: here dotted line indicates the control polygon and solid line (in blue) is obtained after applying subdivision scheme]

I want to calculate the curvature of the following curve (in blue) whose equation is not known.
I shall be thankful.

Comment: Look into equations of ellipses.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an ellipse:  $\left(\frac x4\right)^2+\left(\frac y3\right)^2=1$  Of course, as it is given as a graph, you can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Curvature is the
rate of change of slope
(measured from
$0$ to $2\pi$).
So the first step
is to estimate the slope.

Using the fact that
a good estimate for
$f'(x)$
is
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$,
we could estimate the slope
of the figure shown
at one of the points
as the slope of the line
connecting
the two surrounding points.
You might want
to throw in
some kind of
weighting factor
depending on the distances
between the
central point
and its two neighbors.

Once these two slopes
have been determined,
a center from which
the change in slope is measured
needs to be determined.
A possibility is to
draw the lines
perpendicular to the slope lines
through the point at which
the slope is being estimated.
The intersection of
these perpendiculars
for two consecutive points
gives a center.
From this center,
the change in slope
can be estimated,
and the  radius of curvature then found.
There will be two distances -
the distance from this center
to the two points -
so some average of these
radii should be used.

I know that
this is fairly handwavey,
but it sems reasonable to me.